# Heroku pg:backups fails with "an error"

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This kind of arbitrary failure seems to be part of the Rails app learning curve, so I apologize for such a simpleminded question, but: '`heroku pgbackups:capture`' is simply...failing. That is, I captured the URL for my Postgresql database on heroku, then pasted it into:

> % heroku pgbackups:capture postgres://`<secret rest of db URL>`

...and get the following response:

> Database on ec2-50-19-215-116.compute-1.amazonaws.com  ----backup--->  b003
>
> Pending...  \
>
> !    An error occurred and your backup did not finish.

Helpful, eh? Any clues how I can suss this out? Thanks for help with a naive question.

Steve Upstill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it persists, contact support - there's not a huge amount you can do here.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that the connection count for my database was exhausted. I was on a hobby db that only has a max of 20 concurrent connections, and they were all in use.  I was able to trigger a backup successfully after freeing up some connections (which you can do e.g. by tuning your connection pools or shutting down some nodes).

You can see the connection count of your db via the pg add-on UI:

[image]

Comment: ran `heroku restart` to free up some connections and get it to work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running the latest version of the Heroku command-line tool:

```
$ heroku update
```

then re-install the add-on:

```
$ heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

then capture a backup of your primary database ( without specifying the DB path, from ineer local branch on your local machine ):

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
```

Comment: That seems to have done it. Funny, I had just installed the heroku client and pgbackups earlier in the day, and tried the capture without specifying the URL. Different result then: it was in Pending state for ages before I killed it.

Hmph. One of those things, I guess. Thanks for the nudge.